# ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint how to get this solved?

Tags: oracle

```sql
CREATE TABLE report(
    report_id NUMBER(5),
    description VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    status VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    bicycle_id NUMBER(5),
    cust_id NUMBER(5),
    staff_id NUMBER(5),
CONSTRAINT ad_reportid_pk PRIMARY KEY (report_id),
CONSTRAINT ad_bicycle_fk FOREIGN KEY (bicycle_id) REFERENCES bicycle(bicycle_id),
CONSTRAINT ad_custid_fk FOREIGN KEY (cust_id) REFERENCES customer(cust_id),
CONSTRAINT ad_staffid_fk FOREIGN KEY (staff_id) REFERENCES staff(staff_id)
);
```

Above is the SQL script when I'm creating a table and it thrown me error with ORA-02264. I am neither drop the table nor creating that table. Tried to run this script

```sql
SELECT * FROM user_constraints WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'ad_bicycleid_fk'
```

and it showed no data.

Answer (score 1):

All object names are stored in uppercase unless you mention it in double quotes while creating an object.
Try this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM user_constraints 
   WHERE upper(CONSTRAINT_NAME) = upper('ad_bicycleid_fk');
```

Comment: thank you.. but I'm still having an issue to either create that table and to drop that table

Comment: Do you get any row in this query? SELECT * FROM user_constraints 
   WHERE upper(CONSTRAINT_NAME) = upper('ad_bicycleid_fk');

Comment: yes I managed to get 1 row of result just now. now I execute the same query and it showed no data...

Comment: my apology... I managed to get 1 row after executing that SQL command... And it is pointing to another table name... DELETE_RULE: NO ACTION...

Comment: That means the ad_bicycle_fk constraint is already used in other table. You can choose another name for constraint in 'report' table. It's good practive to include table name indicator in constraint name e.g. ad_report_bicycle_fk

Comment: thank you for the suggestion... will practice that... I have changed the constraint name in 'report' table, however it appeared to be ORA-00942: table or view does not exist... My goodness

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example which shows one option you might do that.

First, "dummy" tables which are being referenced by columns in the `report` table (why do I need them? Because `create table report` would fail otherwise):

```
SQL> create table bicycle
  2    (bicycle_id  number(5) constraint pk_bic primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create table customer
  2    (cust_id     number(5) constraint pk_cus primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create table staff
  2    (staff_id    number(5) constraint pk_sta primary key);

Table created.
```

The `report` table:

```
SQL> create table report
  2    (report_id   number(5),
  3     description varchar2(200) not null,
  4     status      varchar2(200) not null,
  5     bicycle_id  number(5),
  6     cust_id     number(5),
  7     staff_id    number(5),
  8     --
  9     constraint pk_rep     primary key (report_id),
 10     constraint fk_rep_bic foreign key (bicycle_id)
 11                references bicycle (bicycle_id),
 12     constraint fk_rep_cus foreign key (cust_id)
 13                references customer (cust_id),
 14     constraint fk_rep_sta foreign key (staff_id)
 15                references staff (staff_id)
 16    );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Everything is OK.

Note the way I named constraints, especially foreign keys whose names show - at least approximately - which table references which another table, e.g. `FK_REP_BIC` - it is a **F**oreign **K**ey from table **REP**ort and it references the **BIC**ycle table. I'm not saying that you *must* do it that way, but - Google a little bit, read about *good practices* and find the one you prefer the most.

As of the constraint you couldn't find:

```
SQL> select owner, constraint_type, table_name
  2  from user_constraints
  3  where constraint_name = 'FK_REP_BIC';

OWNER           C TABLE_NAME
--------------- - ---------------
SCOTT           R REPORT

SQL>
```